# TSC: Why does introducing a module declaration effects the contents of the outFile?

Tags: typescript, openlayers

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "module": "amd",
        "target": "es3",
        "declaration": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "outFile": "built/index.js",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "baseUrl": "./node_modules"
    },
    "include": [
        "index.ts",
        "ol4-lab",
        "typings/index.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

Code:

```
import Map from "ol/map";
```

Produces:

```
define("ol4-lab/examples/index", ["require", "exports", "node_modules/ol/map", "node_modules/ol/layer/tile", ...
```

But introducing this declaration effects the produced code:

```
declare module "ol/map" {
    export default ol.Map;
}
```

Now it produces:

```
define("ol4-lab/examples/index", ["require", "exports", "ol/map", "node_modules/ol/layer/tile",
```

Notice the "node_modules/" was removed from "ol/map".

QUESTION: Is this a defect or by design and how can it be avoided?